# Algotrader open source project not recognized as java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded the open source edition of AlgoTrader from google code and imported it in Eclipse. There are two project algotrader and algotrader-strat. But the problem is that they are not recognized by eclipse as a java projects. I realized that when I tried to add a jar file and build the path.  There is not “J” on the project folder.  So my question is there a way eclipse to recognize these projects as java. And if yes how can it be done?
Thanks.

https://code.google.com/p/algo-trader/wiki/AlgoTraderDocumentation#Installation

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a quick look at the mentioned projects (I do not know them).

From what I can see, the directories you imported are the parent projects (from a Maven point of view), whose modules are in some sub-directories. For example the algotrader project contains a sub-directory called `code`. This one is an Eclipse project that can be imported.

Answer (score 5):

As it uses maven, maybe you can just regenerate the Elipse project files. Something like:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```